# Run Active Directory shell commands using C#

Tags: c#, shell, scripting, active-directory, cmd

I am writing a module which will be executing any kind of shell commands related to Active Directory and other shell commands on a particular domain controller.

Some of command are working but some of commands are not working properly.

Here is the code

```
public static void ExecuteShellCommand(string _FileToExecute, string _CommandLine, ref string _outputMessage, ref string _errorMessage)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process _Process = null;

    try
    {
       _Process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

       string _CMDProcess = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"{0}\cmd.exe", new object[] { Environment.SystemDirectory });

       string _Arguments = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", new object[] { _FileToExecute });

       _Arguments = string.Format(" /C \"{0}\"", _Arguments);
       Console.WriteLine("---aruguments quering : cmd.exe" + _Arguments);                
       System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo _ProcessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(_CMDProcess, _Arguments);               
       _ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;                
       _ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;                
       _ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       _ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
       _ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
       _Process.StartInfo = _ProcessStartInfo;
       //_ProcessStartInfo.Domain = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain().Name;

       _Process.Start();

       _errorMessage = _Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
       _Process.WaitForExit();

       _outputMessage = _Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
       _Process.WaitForExit();
    }
    catch (Exception _Exception)
    {                
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
       _Process.Close();
       _Process.Dispose();
       _Process = null;
    }
}

CommandExecutionEngine.ExecuteShellCommand("nltest", "/logon_query /server:india.cobra.net", ref output, ref error);
Console.WriteLine("output for dir : " + output + " error : " + error);
```

Commands:

```
repadmin /showrepl

dcdiag

dcdiag /s:<dcname
```

command nltest executing but not returning any result. Where the other mentioned commands giving error is not recognized as internal or external command. Where if I execute command directly from console its working fine.

Here I am invoking a process under the context of domain administrator account so that I will not be have any permission issues.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why do you execute `cmd`? Can't you call your command directly?

Comment: because I have to create generic module for all set of commands. How to call commands directly?

Comment: I meant instead of calling `cmd /c "dcdiag"` in your `Process` object, just call `dcdiag`.

Comment: that will give error system can't find file. I have to run all these commands on a particular domain controller not on local machine. So I thought that executing using cmd will be best approach.

Comment: The `Process` class starts processes just like you would start them using the "run" command from your start menu. I'm not sure how it would help to use `cmd`. I don't think you would enter "cmd /c whatever" into the "run" window just to execute "whatever". Something like `Process.Start("repadmin", "/showrepl")` is sufficient to start this program with the specified arguments. To start a process remotely on another machine, you can't use the `Process` class, but have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777466/how-can-you-run-a-process-on-another-computer-in-net).

Comment: I spent some time on this and come to know that command is not a problem. You can run these commands easily, but under which account the cmd.exe is invoked is issue here. Like I am executing this exe under which account and when I execute this function under which account it will initiate the cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

Possibly since UseShellExecute = false, the application location is not being found.  Use the full path.